# Want to use Java 6 Hashmap implementation in Java 8

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

Currently I am facing an issue during migration of project from java 6 to java 8. I am using Hashmap to store some data and iterating it to form a list to render on UI. Change in the compiler changing the order of fields in Hashmap (may be as per new implementation of java 8 hashmap) causing fields in new random order. This is breaking my sequence on UI. Is there any way I can have similar implementation of any collection in Java 8 similar to Hashmaps in Java 6. I need this as an intermediate solution before I go ahead with changing the entire implementation. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Use a `LinkedHashMap`?

Comment: XY problem. You made a mistake originally, and now you're seeking to perpetuate it. If you wanted a predictable order, why did you use a collection that doesn't guarantee it? Use a `TreeMap`.

Comment: Order of elements in a `HashMap` is **arbitrary**. Even the Java 6 javadoc said so: *"This class makes **no guarantees as to the order** of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time."* If your code relies on `HashMap` order, then your code is flawed/broken and needs to change. Do not perpetuate/hack the problem by cloning Java 6 code in Java 8. Fix *your* code. --- As for an intermediate solution, don't upgrade. Fixing code before upgrading. You did say "intermediate", as-in very short-term, right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a classic XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

The source code for Java 6's HashMap is available under the GPL, you could copy it and use it in the application if this license isn't an issue.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java

This should only be used as a temporary solution -- depending on the iteration order of HashMaps is a bad idea in general. The LinkedHashMap solution could work if it'd take significant refactoring to fix the dependence on iteration order.

Comment: Thanks Lymia, yes I need to go back and refactor code but wanted some quick and temporary fix.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like madness to depend on one random ordering rather than another random ordering. Anyway, if possible, you should:

- Use a [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). This maintains insertion order, so will let you insert objects in the order you want them to come out.

Or:

- When iterating/using the contents of the map, pull the objects into a `List` so that you can sort or rearrange it according to whatever criteria you need.

If you absolutely need to, it is possible to use the JDK 6 HashMap code in a Java 8 application. Here are the relevant files for the current update of Java 6:

- http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java
- http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractMap.java

It seems that `HashMap` depends on a couple of package-private fields in its superclass `AbstractMap`, so you will need them both. Change the `package` statement in each file to fit your application and give each one an import statement for `java.util.*` and it will work.

And please remember the statement at the top of the [`HashMap` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

Comment: Thanks a lot Boann. I understand we should have used some ordered collection, but as it is out of control now, I needed some quick turn around. I will try out this option.